# What is the opposite of !!this.checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I am trying to uncheck a box when another is checked. I have it all working except I need to know the opposite of `this.checked` as well as the opposite of `!!this.checked`.

Basically I want to use my present method which works rather than change all my code for a new method, so I just need to know the opposite.

`this.checked` checks the checkbox, but I want the opposite so when it runs it UNchecks it.

Comment: can you post your related code portion

Comment: Not sure I understand. The opposite of the boolean value this.checked is just `!this.checked`.
If you want to uncheck a box via JavaScript, you can always try `this.checked = false;`
Also, not sure exactly what you need, but would radio buttons work here? That way, one unchecks when the other gets selected.

Comment: it's ok several others already posted the answer below, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The opposite of `!!this.checked` is just `!this.checked`, i.e.

```
chrome.storage.local.set({'theIDofmyCheckbox2': !this.checked});
```

Explanation:

`!this.checked` is `true` when `this.checked` is `false` or any other falsey value (like `0`, `null`...), and is `false` otherwise.

`!!this.checked` is the opposite of this.

Comment: THANKS!! Perfect, works! :D I will accept as soon as it lets me and I will upvote as soon as I have 15 rep so I can.

Answer (score 3):

Using `!!` twice basically converts whatever value is after it into a boolean (`true` or `false`) if it isn't a boolean already .

If you have:

```
var example = 0;
```

and call:

```
console.log( !!example );
```

You'll get `false`, because `0` is `false` as a boolean.

When you use `!` once, you're getting a boolean, but the oppose of it's value, so taking the `example` variable again:

```
console.log( !example );
```

This would log `true`, because the opposite of `0` as a boolean is `true`.

---

So, the opposite of `!!this.checked` would be `!this.checked`, which in your scenario would be `true` (since `this.checked` was originally `false`)

---

Maybe this will help you understand a bit more:

```
var foo = false,
    bar = true;

!foo; // true: opposite of false is true.
!bar; // false: opposite of true is false.

!!foo; // false: opposite of false is true, opposite of true is false.
!!bar; // true: opposite of true is false, opposite of false is true.
```

Comment: huh?? Doesn't seem to answer the question.

Comment: If this doesn't answer your question or give you an idea on how to solve it, then I'm not sure what more to tell you, sorry. :L

Answer (score 2):

!! returns a not not.
say you have a `var test = true;`

`!test` becomes `false`

`!!test` becomes `true` again.

Rememebr it by - *bang! bang! you're boolean.*

Comment: Thanks! You are second to the punch but this also answers my question! Thank you! `(CupawnTae was first)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this for is checked:

```
chrome.storage.local.set({'theIDofmyCheckbox2': $(this).is(':checked')});
```

Try this for is not checked:

```
chrome.storage.local.set({'theIDofmyCheckbox2': !$(this).is(':checked')});
```

! = not,
!! = not not = is

Comment: hmm, interesting but not quite the opposite. Others had the better answer but thank you as this is useful.

Comment: obviously i couldn't be the one who voted you down since you need 125 rep to do that so if that's why you downvoted i would appreciate if you removed it.